# Como bloquear arquivos de diretório recursivamente?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Estou tentando bloquear todos arquivos de um determinado diretório com exceção de *.js* , *.jpg* , *.css* , *.gif* , *.png*.

Tenho este código, mas não está funcionando como eu quero:

```
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$">
   order deny,allow
   allow from all
</Files>
```

Alguém poderia me orientar onde estou errando ?

Comment: Você esta usando `.htaccess` em seu projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure em seu [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) as seguintes diretivas:

```
<Files ~ "\.*$">
        Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch ".*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

A primeira diretiva irá bloquear todas as extensões, a segunda irá permitir as extensões informadas.

Isso será aplicado recursivamente a partir do diretório informado no [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) de seu VirtualHost.

Comment: isso eu ponho no .htaccess correto ?

Comment: meu servidor he cpanel nao sei como configurar sem ser pelo htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Olá, adicione na pasta que deseja bloquear os arquivos o seguinte código abaixo no .htaccess. Obs.: Este bloqueio é recursivo.

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all

# Allow access to html files
<Files ~ "^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$">
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: creio que a pergunta é como bloquear `recursivamente`, evitando ter que colocar um arquivo `.htaccess` em cada pasta...

Comment: Se colocar na raiz, pegará todos os diretórios abaixo e assim sucessivamente. Se colocar em uma pasta chamada assets por exemplo, afetará todas as sub pastas de assets.